# Custom defined form Constraint throws a null pointer exception

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I have a problem with defining a custom `Constraint` on my form. This is my form:

```scala
val form = Form(
  mapping(
    "field" -> boolean
)(MyForm.apply)(MyForm.unapply)
```

If I do the following:

```scala
val form = Form(
  mapping(
    "field" -> boolean
)(MyForm.apply)(MyForm.unapply).verifying("my constraint", f => f.field == true)
```

then it works fine. However, if I try to use the following custom defined `Constraint` , then a null pointer exception is thrown and I do not knowing why:

```scala
val form = Form(
  mapping(
    "field" -> boolean
)(MyForm.apply)(MyForm.unapply).verifying(myconstraint)

val myconstraint : Constraint[MyForm] = Constraint("myconstraint")({
   form => 
      if(form.field == true){
          Valid
      }else {
        Invalid(Seq(ValidationError("problem")))
      }
})
```

I tried to use `println` to debug but I nothing is printed in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `myconstraint` definition above the `form` definition like so

```
val myconstraint : Constraint[MyForm] = Constraint("myconstraint")({ ...
...
val form = Form( ...
```

due to possible forward reference problem where we end up referencing an uninitialised value.